# simple struts application needs internet to run?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, struts

I'm developing a simple struts application.

tools used:

- IDE: Eclipse helios
- server: jboss 4.0.5
  installed plugin for eclipse from site:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/nightly/trunk/
selected only struts development.

everything was set fine.

created dynamic web application and added struts capabilities.
struts is: 1.2
it automatically copies tld files to WEB-INF. in jsp files the taglib uri pointing to the web-inf directory.

When i using html struts tag all tags are working fine: except

my tag is:

```
<html:form action="/new.do" >
<html:text property="uname">uname</html:text>
<html:submit></html:submit>
```

..
the simple project, it takes some input and forward to anothe jsp page thats it.

In absense of internet the project is not working but in presense of internet its working fine, action is forwarding.

in absense of internet its throwing the error as below:

```
11:56:05,375 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:798)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:506)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_html_form_0(index_jsp.java:130)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_html_html_0(index_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:75)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

PLEASE ANYBODY HELP ON THIS!!!
thanks in advance

Comment: Jboss 4.0.5 is real old. If you want to stay with jboss4, then at least upgrade to 4.2.3 - may not solve your issue, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the problem...Taglibs URL are `absolute` not `relative`... and thats why when internet is On it works.. Otherwise it dont.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to include the library locally in your eclipse, than referring to an online resource.